# Does $A^{*}B^{*}=-B^{*}A^{*}$ imply $AB=-BA$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are densely-defined operators on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and let $A^{*}$ and $B^{*}$ be their adjoints, which are assumed to be densely-defined as well. Moreover, suppose $A^{*}B^{*}=-B^{*}A^{*}$. Does it follow that $AB=-BA$? I think this is indeed true because, if $\psi \in D((AB+BA)^{*})$, then:
$$A^{*}B^{*}=-B^{*}A^{*} \Rightarrow (A^{*}B^{*}+B^{*}A^{*})\psi = 0 \Rightarrow (AB+BA)^{*}\psi = 0$$
Thus, one have:
$$\langle \varphi, (AB+BA)^{*}\psi\rangle = ((AB+BA)\varphi, \psi \rangle = 0$$
and, because the above holds for every $\varphi,\psi$, we can take $\psi = (AB+BA)\varphi$ to conclude that $||(AB+BA)\varphi|| = 0$ for every $\varphi$, that is, $(AB+BA)\varphi = 0$ for every $\varphi$, which implies $AB+BA=0$. But is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Isn't $(A^*)^*=A$ and $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$?

Comment: @QED if these are bounded, yes. But these are densely defined, not necessarily bounded. I don't think these relations hold, do they?

Comment: In the third line You mean $\psi\in D((AB+BA)^*)$? Later you swich and apply $AB+BA$ to $\psi$, not knowing if $\psi\in D(AB+BA)$.

Comment: Yes! For sure! I'm going to edit it! Thanks!

Comment: And now you conclude $\langle (AB+BA)\varphi,\psi\rangle =0$ for every $\varphi\in D(AB+BA)$ and $\psi\in D((AB+BA)^*)$. But is it that $(AB+BA)\varphi\in D((AB+BA)^*)$??